# Trying to parse JSON from a url using C#

Tags: c#, .net, json

I have an exe file I wrote in .NET which I want to read a .json file from a URI, and return a value in string format. I am pretty new to .NET and c# but can easily do this in PowerShell (using Invoke-RestMethod). I don't want to use an external library such as json.net (would like to distribute this as a single .exe). The only thing I found so far was System.Runtime.Serialization.Json - which looks like it will work but also seems extremely complex and difficult to use. Is this the library I should be using to perform this simple task? Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: See this answer for a simple example of System.Runtime.Serialization.Json: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15894241/19020

Answer (score 3):

import System.Web.Script.Serialization, then use JavaScriptSerializer object.

Answer (score 1):

`System.Runtime.Serialization.Json` really isn't all that bad. Yes, it is the library you should use if you don't want to go third-party.

The exception to this is if your JSON is trivial. If it's trivial, just do the string parsing yourself.

Comment: The JSON has just a few objects. I can definitely parse it myself with much less code. I will do that.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to parse your own JSON I think the System.Runtime.Serialization.Json namespace is your best bet without using an external library..

JSON.NET is the best if you can use an external library though